# uniq -u with specific column

Tags: shell, unix, uniq

I want to print lines based on value in particular column that appear only once. In example below, val2 and val3 appear only once.

**Input**

```
val1,1
val2,2
val1,3
val3,4
```

**Output**

```
val2,2
val3,4
```

`uniq -u` does not seem to have option of specifying a column. I also tried `sort -t, -k1,1 -u` but that prints every row once.

Comment: do you want to keep the order?

Comment: no.. order does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{c[$1]++; t[$1]=$0} END {for(k in c) {if (c[k]==1) print t[k]}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem for awk, assume that the command that produces

```
val1,1
val2,2
val1,3
val3,2
```

Is called `foo`, then pipe it into awk like so:

```
foo | awk -F, '$2 == 2 {print}'
```

Comment: I misread your problem, modifying the awk code to answer your question

Comment: My problem statement was not clear probably. sorry for that. I want to print rows, which have values in column 1, appear only once. In above example, val2 and val3 appear only once. It does not to do anything with second column 2.